# Maximizing $\sqrt6xy+4yz$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization

Let $x, y, z$ be real numbers such that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$.

Let $A$ be maximum value of $\sqrt6xy+4yz$. Find $2A^2-4$.

An initial approach was trying out the inequality $\text{RMS-AM-GM}$. Then I tried a parametric substitution: $x=\cos\alpha, y=\sin\alpha cos\beta, z=\sin\beta \sin\alpha$.
How would you go about this?

Comment: Set $y=\cos\alpha$

Comment: Just for your curiosity, using Lagrange multipliers would easily show the values of $x,y,z,A$. I suppose that this is off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

$$1=x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2+ay^2+(1-a)y^2+z^2 \ge 2\sqrt{a}xy+2\sqrt{(1-a)}yz \quad (\because \text{AM-GM})$$

$$a=\frac{3}{11}$$

Note that $2\sqrt{a}:2\sqrt{(1-a)}=\sqrt{6}:4$.

Let $2\sqrt{a}= \sqrt{6}k$, and multiply $k$ on each side.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can do the latter. But can you explain the AM-GM step?

Comment: @SatD, Sorry, I made a mistake. Will correct it.

Comment: @SatD $x^2+ay^2 \ge 2\sqrt{ax^2y^2}=2xy\sqrt{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

As $y$ is repeated in  $\sqrt6xy+4yz,$

WLOG choose  $y=\cos\alpha, x=\sin\alpha\cos\beta, z=\sin\beta\sin\alpha$

$\sqrt6xy+4yz=\cos\alpha\sin\alpha(\sqrt6\cos\beta+4\sin\beta)$
$=\dfrac{\sin2\alpha}2\cdot\sqrt{22}\cos\left(\beta-\arccos\sqrt{\dfrac6{22}}\right)$

$\le\dfrac{\sqrt{22}}2$

The equality occurs if $\sin2\alpha=1$ and $\beta=\arccos\sqrt{\dfrac6{22}}$

$\iff\alpha=180^\circ n+45^\circ$ and $\cos\beta=\sqrt{\dfrac6{22}};\sin\beta=\dfrac4{\sqrt{22}}$