# How to find $R$ if the maximum value of $x-y+z$ under the restriction $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ is $\sqrt{27}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima, substitution, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Find $R$ if the maximum value of $x-y+z$ under the constraint $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$ is $\sqrt{27}$.

This is an extrema finding problem so we can use Lagrange multipliers here.
$$
\begin{cases}
1=c2x\\
-1=c2y\\
1=c2z 
\end{cases}
$$
Then:
$$
x=z\Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2+x^2=R^2\Leftrightarrow2x^2+y^2=R^2\\
\Leftrightarrow y=\pm\sqrt{R^2-2x^2}
$$
We can plug the findings into $x-y+z$:
$$
x\pm\sqrt{R^2-2x^2}+x=2x\pm\sqrt{R^2-2x^2}
$$
But it doesn't seem to lead me anywhere. How to I proceed?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1685072/maximizing-sqrt6xy4yz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve all 3 equations symmetrically as
$$c=\frac{1}{2x}=-\frac{1}{2y}=\frac{1}{2z}. $$
This gives $$x=-y=z, $$
and the equation of the sphere gives
$$3x^2=R^2 \implies x= \pm R/\sqrt3 .$$
The two critical points are then $$ \pm R/\sqrt{3}(1,-1,1).$$
I'll leave it to you to find which one is the maximum.

Comment: In fact, it does not mind which is the maximum since both fulfil the restriction, so any of them provides the value of $R^2$.

Comment: @Yos, you're right, I'll fix it.

Comment: I was thinking: in your example $c=\frac{1}{2x}=-\frac{1}{2y}=\frac{1}{2z}$ how do we know that  $x,y,z\neq 0$?

Comment: @Yos since $2xc =1,2yc=-1,-2zc=1$.

Answer (score 2):

This is just use of Cauchy inequality:
$$(x-y+z)^2\leq 3(x^2+y^2+z^2)= 3R^2$$
Maximum is reachead when $x:-y:z = 1:1:1$
thus $x=\sqrt{3}$ and $R=3$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the substitution

$$x=R\cos u\sin v, y=-R\cos u\cos v, z=R\sin u$$
where $\displaystyle u,v\in[0,\frac\pi2]$.

(Note that $y$ is chosen to be negative so that it can give maximal $x-y+z$.)

\begin{align}
x-y+z &= R(\cos u\sin v+\cos u \cos v+\sin u)\\
&=R\left(\sqrt2\cos u\sin(v+\frac\pi4)+\sin u\right)\\
&\le R(\sqrt2\cos u+\sin u )=f(u)
\end{align}

Differentiate w.r.t $u$,
$$f'(u)=R(\sqrt2\sin u-\cos u)$$
$$f'(u)=0\iff\tan u =\frac1{\sqrt2}\implies\cos u=\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3},\sin u=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}$$

Therefore 
$$\sqrt{27}=R\left(\sqrt2\cdot\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt3}+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)\implies R=3$$